# Patrones de dibujo en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo los ejercicios antes del examen de programación y no consigo hacer este:

"Escribir un programa que reciba un número natural y pinte aproximadamente por pantalla una figura cuadrada usando un patrón de dibujo dado. Por ejemplo, si se lee el número 3, el cuadrado que se dibujará es el siguiente:

[[image: patrón de dibujo[1]]"

De momento tengo esto:

```
    int patron(int n);

    int n;

    int main()
    {
        printf("Introduce el numero natural deseado:\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        patron(n);
    }

    int patron(int n)
    {
        int i, j;

        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
            {
                printf("+---");
            }
            printf("+\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Que devuelve esto:

[image: producto del programa actual]

¿Cómo hago para hacer los cuadradillos con exclamaciones?
Al añadir los saltos de linea, todo se desbarata.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: añade tu código como texto

Comment: edita tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/41354/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
 int patron(int n);

int n;

int main()
{
    printf("Introduce el numero natural deseado:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    patron(n);
}

int patron(int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            printf("+---");
        }
        printf("+\n");
        if(i<n){
           for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
            {
                printf("!   ");
            }
            printf("!\n");  
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no hay ningún if

Comment: sorry for quice decir

Comment: casi, pero la linea de +---+ de abajo del todo falta

Comment: ahi esta probado y todo jeje.

Answer (score 1):

Con este ejercicio, vas a pintar el dibujo linea por linea.
En este caso, las lineas impares siempre serán (+---) y las lineas pares seras (!).
Contrólalo con el contador del primer FOR, dependiendo si es par o impar pintas una cosa u otra.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría de esta forma, modificaría:

```
printf("+\n");
```

Por

```
if(i != n)
    printf("+\n!   !   !   !\n");
else
    printf("+\n");
```

Para que quede algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este ejemplo, `n` es igual a 3.

Comment: Las celdas resultantes han de ser de nxn al introducir n, en cambio esa es de 3x2.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por las aportaciones, he solucionado el problema, aquí está el código final:

```
    int patron(int n);
    int n;

    int main()
    {
        printf("Introduce el numero natural deseado:\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        patron(n);
    }

   int patron(int n)
   {
       int i, j,k, f;

       for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
       {
            for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
            {
                printf("+---");
            }
            printf("+\n");



            for (k=1; k<=n; k++)
            {
                printf("!   ");
            }

            printf("!\n");
            if (i==n){

                for (f=1; f<=n; f++)
                {
                    printf("+---");
                }
                printf("+\n");
            }


        }

        printf("\n");
        return 0;
   }
```

El añadido fue esta zona(no se modificó el resto del código, simplemente se añadió bajo el for anidado):

```
     for (k=1; k<=n; k++)
        {
            printf("!   ");
        }

        printf("!\n");
        if (i==n){

            for (f=1; f<=n; f++)
            {
                printf("+---");
            }
            printf("+\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una alternativa

```
void pintarCuadro(int n)
{

    for(int i=0; i<n+1; i++)
    {
   //    printf("pintar\n");
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("+---");
        }
        printf("+\n");

        if(i<n)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                printf("!   ");
            }
            printf("!\n");

        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    pintarCuadro(7);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mucho mas eficiente, gracias.

Comment: Y si le quitas toda llave innecesaria, mucho más legible además (es legible tal y como está, pero en códigos más grandes es horrible).

Answer (score 1):

Te muestro una forma alternativa, que te deja elegir el ALTO y el ANCHO interno de cada celda.

Además, en lugar de realizar múltiples `for` anidados, *precalculamos* las líneas a mostrar, de forma que, en lugar de `x * y` iteraciones, realizamos solo 3: precalcular las líneas *de cierre*, precalcular las lineas *internas*, y un bucle final para mostrarlas.

En el `for` final, comprobamos si estamos en una línea anterior a la primera línea de *cruce*; si ya la pasamos, utilizamos el *modulo* (resto) de la división para saber si tenemos que mostrar una línea *interna* de la celda, o una línea *de cruce*.

Como último punto, compila desde **C89** en adelante.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ANCHO 2
#define ALTO 2

void showMatrix( int x ) {
  int realWidth = ( ANCHO * x ) + x + 1;
  char up[realWidth + 1];
  char inter[realWidth + 1];
  int idx;

  memset( up, '-', realWidth - 1 );
  up[realWidth] = 0;

  for( idx = 0; idx < realWidth; idx += ANCHO + 1 )
    up[idx] = '+';

  memset( inter, ' ', realWidth - 1 );
  inter[realWidth] = 0;

  inter[0] = '!';
  inter[realWidth - 1] = '!';
  for( idx = ANCHO + 1; idx < realWidth; idx += ANCHO + 1 )
    inter[idx] = '!';

  realWidth = ( ALTO * x ) + x + 1;

  printf( "%s\n", up );
  for( idx = 1; idx < realWidth ; ++idx )
    if( idx <  ALTO )
      printf( "%s\n", inter );
    else
      printf( "%s\n", idx % ( ALTO + 1 ) ? inter : up );
}

int main( void ) {
  showMatrix( 6 );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estaba limitado ha realizar el ejercicio con funciones y estructuras de control. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Espero que te valga al menos como `inspiración` para futuros problemas ;-)

Comment: Yo también!! Gracias